# NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined when I install package - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to install the package. But there is the error. How can I fix it?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install zopyx.convert2
Collecting zopyx.convert2
  Using cached zopyx.convert2-2.4.6.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-e90y11sx\zopyx.convert2\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        desc = unicode(file(os.path.join('docs', 'source', 'README.rst')).read().strip(), 'utf-8')
    NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find something similar? I'm looking for HTML2RTF converter and had same issue with zopyx.converter2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like this library, which has not been updated since 2012, is not compatible with Python 3 and they haven't properly indicated that in the pypi metadata.

The [source code is here](https://github.com/zopyx/zopyx.convert2), if you can't find an alternative library, you may be able to update it to python3 yourself and either make a pull request or a fork.